# Defining unicode character in the context of another (pdfLaTeX)

Tags: unicode, catcodes, scoping

This is a bit of a strange question.

Suppose for some unknown reason I want the character ɲ (U+0272, 0xc9 0xb2) to say "bye", the character ɳ (U+0273, 0xc9 0xb3) to say "aww", and the sequence ɲɳ to say "hi".

To that effect I have written the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\makeatletter

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0272}{bye\ }

{
    \catcode`^^c9=12
    \catcode`^^b2=12
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\expandafter\tmp\csname u8:^^c9^^b2\endcsname
}

\def\test{\@ifnextchar^^c9{\@test}{\tmp}}
\def\@test#1{\@ifnextchar^^b3{hi\ \@gobble}{\tmp^^c9}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0272}{\test}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0273}{aww\ }

\begin{document}
ɲɲɲɳɳɳ
\end{document}
```

Now this actually works: it does indeed output "bye bye hi aww aww". My question then is how "safe" this is. Suppose I have two unicode characters u1 and u2, both outside of the U+0000 to U+007f range. I define u1u2 to be some arbitrary macro, while preserving their individual functions (for example, u1 may have already been defined by a package, and u2 might throw the character not supported error), as done in the code above.

Are there u1 and u2 such that the above procedure does not work as intended, or is this perfectly fine?

Comment: If you're "careful enough" you might be safe? But be careful on what "careful enough" means, you might need to be alignment-safe, edef-safe, fully expandable etc. Usually it should work just fine and I can't think of a counterexample at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to support combining characters, perhaps?

Comment: @egreg If possible then yes, that's the plan.

Comment: @user202729 I hadn't considered any of these cases, so if it works in them it isn't by design. How does one go about testing for these?

Comment: By the way, about combining character the technical issue is that you could support them if you e.g. redefine `o` to be an active character; however if you do that then it's almost impossible to use it normally e.g. in control character names or things like TikZ keyword `node`.

Comment: @user202729 I only plan on using characters past ASCII 127.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question then is how "safe" this is

It is safe enough but it does depend on the internals of inputenc UTF-8 support which could (and have in the past) change.

> Are there u1 and u2 such that the above procedure does not work

The version you show only works for the unicode range taking two octets in UTF-8. For higher values you would need to to check 3 or 4 bytes for the following character.

> `\tmp`

I know this is just an example, but as people copy code from old posts, it is worth saying this should be an internal command specfic to U+0272 so it doesn't get over-written by anything else that uses a `\tmp` command.